# How to call a method in second from first class in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, automated-tests

In C# how to call a method in second class from first class

In my second class, instead of entering the  username, password or company name again , i just wanted to call the method of the first class name.

How i can do that? i have tried my best but i cannot solve this? In many class files im writing the same code again, instead of doing that i just wanted call the method name.

### First Class:

```
namespace Example.UITest
 {
 public class LoginTests : AbstractSetup
 {
    public LoginTests(Platform platform) : base(platform)
    {
        }
     [Test]
    public void Login_SuccessfullAuthentication_SuccessfullLogin()
    {
        
        //Enter Username, company name & Password
        app.EnterText(x => x.Marked("Username"), "annby");
        app.EnterText(x => x.Marked("Company name"), "sara");
        app.EnterText(x => x.Marked("Password"), "sara");
        //Tapping "Sign in" button after submitting user credentials
        app.Tap(x=>x.Text("Sign in"));

  }
  }
  

}
```

### Second Class:

```
namespace Example.UITest
 {
 public class AppoinmentTest : AbstractSetup
 {
    public AppoinmentTest(Platform platform) : base(platform)
    {
    }
    [Test]
    public void CreateAppoinment() { 
       //Here i want to call the method
        app.Tap(x => x.Text("Sign in"));
        app.WaitForElement(x => x.Id("action_bar_title"), timeout:     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        app.Tap(x => x.Id("action_bar_title"));
        }}
}
```

Comment: Create an instance of your first class and call the method. WHere is the problem?

Comment: @ragesh-ragav-1993 will appreciate if you mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should extract the login logic to a specific method and then use it in the `Login_SuccessfullAuthentication_SuccessfullLogin` and `CreateAppoinment`.

I suggest to move it to your `AbstractSetup` because you will need ti it more places.

Example:

```
public abstract class AbstractSetup
{    
    public void DoLogin()
    {
        //Enter Username, company name & Password
        app.EnterText(x => x.Marked("Username"), "annby");
        app.EnterText(x => x.Marked("Company name"), "sara");
        app.EnterText(x => x.Marked("Password"), "sara");
        //Tapping "Sign in" button after submitting user credentials
        app.Tap(x=>x.Text("Sign in"));
    }   

}   

[Test]
public void Login_SuccessfullAuthentication_SuccessfullLogin()
{
    DoLogin();
}

[Test]
public void CreateAppoinment() 
{ 
    DoLogin();
    app.WaitForElement(x => x.Id("action_bar_title"), timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    app.Tap(x => x.Id("action_bar_title"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try To Mark your method as Static in the first class like so:

   `public static void Login_SuccessfullAuthentication_SuccessfullLogin()
    {...}`

after that you could call is like so :

```
LoginTests.Login_SuccessfullAuthentication_SuccessfullLogin();
```

2. Or Create an object from the first class and call its method:

   `AppoinmentTest myTest = new AppoinmentTest(platform);
       myTest.Login_SuccessfullAuthentication_SuccessfullLogin();`

Comment: This is a duplicate of my question. Please remove this.

Comment: @jzeferino its showing an error  "Platform is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

Comment: this wasn't my answer. Are you using my answer? share the code please.

Answer (score 0):

Try making an object of the LoginTests class in Appointment Class. I have made some modifications in your code. Hope they work for you!

```
namespace Example.UITest
 {
 public class LoginTests : AbstractSetup
 {
    public LoginTests(Platform platform) : base(platform)
    {
        }

    public void Login_SuccessfullAuthentication_SuccessfullLogin()
    {

        //Enter Username, company name & Password
        app.EnterText(x => x.Marked("Username"), "annby");
        app.EnterText(x => x.Marked("Company name"), "sara");
        app.EnterText(x => x.Marked("Password"), "sara");
        //Tapping "Sign in" button after submitting user credentials
        app.Tap(x=>x.Text("Sign in"));

  }
  }
  }
 // THIS IS MY SECOND CLASS. 
namespace Example.UITest
 {
 public class AppoinmentTest : AbstractSetup
 {
     LoginTests lt = new LoginTests(); //object of class LoginTests

    public AppoinmentTest(Platform platform) : base(platform)
    {
    }


    public void CreateAppoinment() { 
       lt.Login_SuccessfullAuthentication_SuccessfullLogin()              //Here i want to call the login method before doing below functionality
        app.Tap(x => x.Text("Sign in"));
        app.WaitForElement(x => x.Id("action_bar_title"), timeout:     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        app.Tap(x => x.Id("action_bar_title"));
        }}
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of my question. Please remove this. Thank you.